# Transition with javascript, moving object

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I am trying to make transition of the height, but with JavaScript. 
As I can see, it doesn't work, so I'll need your help.
Here's the code and bellow I'll explain you my idea.

```css
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    top = 0;
    left = 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show">

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById('button');
        var height = document.getElementById('myDIV').clientHeight;
        
        for(i = x.style.top; i <= height; i++){
            x.style.top = i + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

So here's the idea: 'height' contains the height of the DIV, I use the loop to increase the value of 'top' in order to move it trough the window, like transition. 'i' is variable which contains the current value of 'top' and while i is smaller than height it increases and saves the current value in top.

Comment: `css` should be `top:0;left:0;`

Comment: it doesn't work anyways

Comment: You are also missing `;` following `i<=height` at `for` loop.

Comment: could it be because myDIV is hidden? and how I can fix it? because I want for myDIV to remain hidden

Comment: `<script>` containing `myFunction` should be placed before `onclick="myFunction()"`

Comment: `height` is `0`. What are you expecting `height` to be?

Comment: well, I expect to be the height of myDIV

Comment: Where is the `height` of `#myDiv` set?

Comment: In the declaration of height (var height = document.getElementById('myDIV').clientHeight;)

Comment: That gets the `.clientHeight`, does not set `height`.

Comment: but in my html document the value of myDIV's display is none by default

Comment: Why do you expect `.clientHeight` to be other than `0`? See https://jsfiddle.net/xsuorhg5/

Comment: yes this is what i want to get the height of the div in the current window

Comment: because i thought that it gets the height in the different windows

Comment: so I have to set a height for the div?

Comment: I saw it but i want to move slowly, smoothly

Comment: You can set the `height` at `css` or at `style` attribute of element. If you are trying to get height of `window` you can use `window.innerHeight` or `window.outerHeight`

Comment: well I want to get the height of the div not for the whole window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `height` of `#myDiv` at `style` attribute or `css`, with `display` set to `block`. Use `window.getComputedStyle()` to get the `height` as a number.

You can use `Element.animate()` function of [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) to animate the element `top` from `0` to value set at element `.height`, with `fill` set to `"forwards"`.

```css
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#myDIV {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var settings = ["0px"];

  function toggleAnimation(el, from, to) {
    el.animate([{
        top: from
      }, {
        top: to
      }], {
        duration: 2500,
        iterations: 1,
        fill: "forwards"
      })
      .onfinish = function() {
        settings.reverse(); // reverse `from`, `to` stored at `settings`
      }
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("button");
    var height = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDIV")).height;
    if (!settings[1]) settings[1] = height;
    toggleAnimation(x, settings[0], settings[1]);
  }
</script>

<span id="myDIV">
        <p>Pressure:</p>
        <p>Air gases:</p>
    </span>
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show">
```

Comment: sorry for the bothering you but what changes should I do to make it go back to the top when i click it?

Comment: i have to just reverse the values?

Comment: Yes, set first `top` at `.animate()` to current `top`, second `top` to `0`.

Comment: okay I will try, if I can't do it can I write you again? on private message or smth else?

Comment: You can achieve this yourself by substituting the values at the properties. You can also define a function which swaps the values.

Comment: I know but... :D