# Forcing a repaint / rerender in Chrome after style changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to convert the background color of each of the cells in a 20x20 table on a webpage.

(This is a simplified version of something a bit more complex)
This is my attempt so far:

```
// Changes the color of each cell
function changeTableColor() {
    for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<20; j++){

            if( meetsCriteria(i, j) ){
                // Change the cell's class to set a new background color
                $('#cell'+i+'-'+j).removeClass('old');
                $('#cell'+i+'-'+j).addClass('new');
            }
        }
    }
    alert('Done changing colors');
}
```

This successfully changes all of the background colors of the cell to match the desired result, but it does so all at one time, and the change is only visible after dismissing the alert at the end.

**My goal is to have the cells change visibly one at a time, so that you could watch them change from top-left to bottom-right**

I've found several topics discussing how to force the window to be repainted/rendered such as triggering window resizing, or modifying the visibility of a parent element, but none of these seem to work!

I've also tried adding a wait to slow down the inner loop, to make sure it happens slow enough for me to see, but as mentioned the changes occur after the alert, instead of when the class is set at runtime.

Comment: You can use `.queue()`, `$.map()`, `.promise()` to call functions in sequence. See [Want to repeat animation on div for infinity times in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068359/want-to-repeat-animation-on-div-for-infinity-times-in-jquery), [When the page is loaded,how to make six functions executed by each otherr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567064/when-the-page-is-loaded-how-to-make-six-functions-executed-by-each-otherr/43567433#43567433)

Comment: You can force a reflow synchronously, but not a repaint. You'd have to get rid of your for loops and convert it to asynchronous looping functions.

Comment: @guest271314, I'm not sure about jquery's implementation, but default promises stack is executed before browser's repaint (in chrome since in FF it is executed even before `alert()`'s popup is shown).

Comment: @Kaiido Not sure what you mean? `.then()` chained to `.promise("queueName")` should not be called until each function within `.queue("queueName")` array of functions are called. An additional `$.when()` can placed in array;  `.then()` chained to `.promise("queueName")` is called immediately following last function call.  _"My goal is to have the cells change visibly one at a time, so that you could watch them change from top-left to bottom-right"_.if requirement is for `alert()` to remain in code.

Comment: @guest271314 that's what I mean : https://jsfiddle.net/3rqqt6jg/ open it on chrome, you'll see that the promise execution is made before the page repaint. I know that alert should be removed, but it's a good way to stop js execution, and to see when repaints really occur. And even [when multiple promises are chained](https://jsfiddle.net/3rqqt6jg/), chrome somehow delays the repaint after the execution of all js, and considers Promises as being part of the js flow, just like if it were synchronous.

Comment: @Kaiido Not sure what you mean by "repaint"? https://jsfiddle.net/3rqqt6jg/1/. OP describes performing task for each element in `html` collect or array in sequence, yes? `css` `transition` can also be included within pattern, to render expected effect. The links achieve the requirement described at OP, unless interpreting Question incorrectly.

Comment: A **reflow** is when all elements in the DOM have their CSS rules applied calculated, you can then use it within scripts, and it fixes things like CSS animations. This can be forced asynchronously by calling e.g `elem.offsetWidth`. A **repaint** is when all these rules are actually converted to pixels so that the monitor can display it on screen. This is up to implementors when to trigger it, and can't be forced asynchronously on our side. Chrome does some optimization and don't trigger the repaint even in between of Promises. This question asks how to force a repaint.

Comment: @Kaiido Did not interpret Question the same. If requirement is to set, modify `css` rules directly, OP can use [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), see  [Transition with javascript, moving object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697384/transition-with-javascript-moving-object/43697723#43697723). Or use `CSSOM` to set rules of `.styleSheet` directly. Else, still not gathering what effect you are referencing which is not or cannot be achieved using linked approaches.