# Why blocking event loop does not block css animation?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I do not know the webpage rendering lifecycle - so in the example below I have two hearts - one is animated by js and another one in CSS. When I block an event loop with an `alert` message, CSS heart remains animated.

```js
let scale = true;
setInterval(() => {
  $('.animate-js').css('transform', `scale(${scale ? 1.4 : 1})`);
  scale = !scale;
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.heart {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #e00;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.animate-css {
  animation: beat 2s steps(2, end) infinite;
}


/* Heart beat animation */

@keyframes beat {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heart">I
  <div class="animate-css heart">&#x2665;</div> CSS</div>
<div class="heart">I
  <div class="animate-js heart">&#x2665;</div> JS</div>
<br/>
<button onClick="alert('hurray!')">
I love it too
</button>
```

I'm pretty sure it is due to the fact that CSS animation is being handled outside of javascript event loop, but I'm not sure if my assumption is correct. The closest article that explains internals is this - [Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/). However, it does not go deep enough. I will appreciate if someone explains this or points me to some digestible material to read/watch before I go hardcore and start looking for specs. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance#css-vs-javascript-performance has to do with the thread that's used. See bottom of the page "CSS vs JavaScript performance".

Comment: thanks a lot, @Gerard that is an awesome link you shared!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because implementers are encouraged by the specs to not follow the specs...

`alert()` calls the [pause algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause), which *should* block the current task and cause the event loop to have nothing to do anymore than waiting for the "condition *goal* is met".

Though, this page also has a big warning paragraph stating,

> [Pausing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause) is highly detrimental to the user experience, especially in scenarios where a single [event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop) is shared among multiple documents. User agents are encouraged to experiment with alternatives to [pausing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause), such as [spinning the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) or even simply proceeding without any kind of suspended execution at all, insofar as it is possible to do so while preserving compatibility with existing content. This specification will happily change if a less-drastic alternative is discovered to be web-compatible.

So your UA certainly followed the advice to experiment with a [*spin-the-event-loop*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) alternative, which allows for other tasks to still run, even though the one that called `alert()` has been paused.

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido! Huh, so by saying that you mean it is NOT supposed to animate CSS, right? My initial guess was that browser runs javascript in a separate thread from actual UI rendering.

Comment: @Gerard mentioned a link which says about compositor thread, and that means that UI does not 'interrupts' current task, but just runs CSS animation in a separate thread

Comment: @Ivan yes, the original algo wouldn't allow the rendering task to perform. Even if they ran on different threads. But it is also them who ask for other, better means. So it is to be expected that more and more UA actually go the spinning way.

Comment: @Ivan the event loop doesn't care on how many threads things are done. Threading is at best irrelevant here.

Comment: yea, event loop does not. But the fact itself that css animation is not frosed with blocked event loop means it is not a part of it, means it is a separate thread, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from what I am reading, CSS animation appear to be outside the Javascript event loop. But, while they are running concurrently, you can control the animations with Javascript calls.

Here is a collection of reading material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations

In particular, [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) is the property I think you're after. Setting it to `paused` right before you call the Javascript alert would be how I'd approach it. Once the user clicks the appropriate button in the alert, set the property back to `running` to resume the animation.