# Are javascript style changes calculated immediately?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Considering the following HTML:

```html
<div style="line-height: 20px;">
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 2</p>
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

If I change the `line-height` via Javascript, is it guaranteed that I'll be able to know the new height from the `div` right away?

Or is it safer to use `requestAnimationFrame` to make sure the styles are applied and calculated?

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div.clientHeight); // 60
div.style.lineHeight = "40px";
console.log(div.clientHeight); // 120?
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 20px;">
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 2</p>
    <p style="margin: 0;">Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I get 91 and 151 on Chrome in your snippet

Comment: i get 92 and 152 on chrome in the snippet

Comment: @mplungjan It was because of the margin. I removed it from the elements to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can be sure you'll get the updated value.

`Element.clientHeight`, [among many other properties and methods](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) will trigger a reflow, a.k.a a recalc so its returned value is up to date.

By the way, triggering a synchronous reflow like this is generally frowned upon because the browser has to recalculate all the boxes in the CSSOM, and on big pages, it can take very long.

Ps: to answer the title question, [see this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730/javascript-are-dom-redraw-methods-synchronous/47343090#47343090)

Comment: Very well explained, thanks! Do you know if this also applies to IE?

Comment: Yes, it does apply to any browser following the standards, and it's in the standards since Netscape era.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `requestAnimationFrame()` is the way to go.

Styles won't be recalculated by the time the following line is run.