# Will changing the width of an element cause a reflow after setting visibility: hidden for it?

Tags: browser, repaint, reflow

Take this code snippets for example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#div')
div.style.visibility = "hidden"
div.style.width = "200px"
div.style.visibility = "visible"
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

The first repaint happens when setting `visibility:hidden` and the second happens when setting `visibility: visible`. But between these 2 repaints will setting `width: 200px` cause a reflow?

In my opinion, the element setting `visibility:hidden` still occupies the page space and doesn't disappear from the layout tree(render tree) so here the reflow will happen. But I'm no sure how to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

> The first repaint happens when setting `visibility:hidden` and the second happens when setting `visibility: visible`.

No, the first and only repaint will happen long after. <sub>(well probably in less than 16ms, but it's a long time for us)</sub>

Repaint only happens in the update the rendering phase of the event-loop, which itself only happens when the monitor sends a VSync signal (60 times a second on a 60Hz monitor).
Here you are changing the styles of your element synchronously, before the first paint, so the first `div.style.visibility = "hidden"` is just ignored, the painter will never see that state, when it will kick in, all it will see is the final `visibility = "visible"` state.

> But between these 2 repaints will setting width: 200px cause a reflow?

No, setting the height property of the style doesn't trigger a reflow. Generally, getters do trigger reflow, because only getters need to have updated box positions.
So if you had a line like `document.body.offsetWidth` instead of this height setting, then you'd have forced a reflow.

You can find a list of most triggers [here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), and you can read a bit more on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730/javascript-are-dom-redraw-methods-synchronous/47343090#47343090).