# Measure performance cost of getBoundingClientRect to track table rows passing through the middle of a table's viewable area

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer, getboundingclientrect

I am browsing HTML tables with pages that auto load via javascript & `XMLHttpRequest` calls as the user scrolls. The number of records per page are user defined. The height of the rows can vary. All the code is vanilla `javascript` and all solutions should be likewise.

I am tracking which row is crossing the middle of the table's viewable rows to determine what is the current page. This is used to display the current page number and to determine when to autoload the next page (think of how Acrobat displays the current page number and thumbnail as you scroll through a PDF). My process to do this:

- Use the intersection observer to observe `TR` rows that scroll in and out of the device's viewport. The triggered `tr` will either be at the top or bottom of the viewport.
- Starting at the triggered row, I loop through the `tbody`'s `tr` elements moving toward the middle until I find the `tr` which intersects with it. I can calculate the current page from the `tr`'s custom `data-rownum` attribute.

I discovered that the intersection observer's `boundingClientRect` property is only updated and current for the triggered element, not the other observed row elements. Therefore I can't use it to calculate a row's position on the screen. I have to call `getBoundingClientRect()` for each `tr` to determine its position as I loop through the `tbody`.

My question is how to measure the performance cost of calling `getBoundingClientRect()` - perhaps 20-50 times per scroll - every time the observer triggers a new row being visible. Is there a way to objectively decide the impact?

Is it worth the effort performance-wise to find another solution? The only other solution I have in mind is to start with the triggered row and use the `height` property of each `tr` to calculate it's position on the screen using the triggered `tr` as a starting point. But, in order to do this, I'd have to have a `resizeObserver` set on all the rows to update the height property on resize, since they can be expanded by the user.

Lastly, is there a different direction that would allow me to track all rows that pass through the middle of the viewable `tbody` that would be more efficient?

Comment: If you don't mess with the layout between each gBCR call,  only the first one will have a noticeable impact, all other ones will just be getters of already calculated values. If you do that in the IntersectionObserver callback, and nothing trashed the layout before, then even the first call won't cost anything.

Comment: @Kaiido - This doesn't make sense, since every row has a new `top` value with a scroll.

Comment: Yes, what's costly is that all the layout of all the page has to be recalculated. No, scrolling will invalidate the boxes but not necessarily the layout. viewport_y = absolute_y - viewport_scrolltop. That doesn't require to update the layout. And I did only talk about consecutive calls. The layout would need to be recalced for the IntersectionObserver anyway.

Comment: @Kaiido - Ok, thanks - that is very helpful. I couldn't find documentation on how and when gBCR does calculations.

Comment: A bit oversimplified, but I write some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730/javascript-are-dom-redraw-methods-synchronous/47343090#47343090 However for your question I'm not clear what would be "the best solution".