# scrollIntoView seems to be firing too early after forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following two functions...

```
function sizeSearch(size) {
    const container = document.querySelector('ul.size-ranks');
    const rankElems = container.querySelectorAll('li');
    rankElems.forEach(e => {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        e.classList.remove('active');
    });

    const sizeID = size.replace(/\D/g,'') + '-rank';
    const sizeElem = document.getElementById(sizeID);
    if (sizeElem) {
        sizeElem.classList.add('active');
        sizeElem.style.display = '';
    } else {
        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li class="empty-search">Size not found</li>');
    }
}

function clearSizeSearch() {
    document.querySelectorAll('li.empty-search').forEach(e => e.remove());
    document.querySelectorAll('ul.size-ranks li').forEach(e => e.style.display = '');
    document.querySelector('ul.size-ranks li.active').scrollIntoView();
}
```

The `sizeSearch()` function works fine. When the `clearSizeSearch()` function is called, all of the `<li>` elements reappear as expected, and you can very briefly see the desired `.active` element scroll into view as expected, but then it immediately scrolls back to the top of the container element (or maybe it re-renders that way after the DOM is finished settling?).

If I manually run `document.querySelector('ul.size-ranks li.active').scrollIntoView();` in the console after running `clearSizeSearch()`, then it works fine. That, along with the fact that I can briefly see it scroll into view when running `clearSizeSearch()`, makes it seem like maybe it's running before the prior commands have finished executing, but as far as I've been able to gather, `forEach()` is not async by default, and any commands that come after should not get run until it's done.

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/8bnp7gsq/ If in that fiddle I scroll inside the <ul> (e.g to show "7"), then click the clear button, it scrolls back to the currently active value as expected. If then I type "10" (so that the "not found" message is shown and click again the button, then I have an error in the console because there is no `.active` element in such a case. But in no way I get what you're experiencing. What browser are you using? I first thought it could be [yet another reflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730), but scrollIntoView should take care of everything.

Comment: I'm dumb. Project is using a 3rd party jQuery library on an ancestor element to manipulate the scrollbar. 99.9% sure the issue is related to that. Setting a small timeout before calling `scrollIntoView()` works well enough for this particular use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.

```
function clearSizeSearch() {
    document.querySelectorAll('li.empty-search').forEach(e => e.remove());
    document.querySelectorAll('ul.size-ranks li').forEach(e => e.style.display = '');
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('ul.size-ranks li.active').scrollIntoView();
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the original issue on your end? Could you share a repro case?

Comment: Pretty sure now that the issue is related to a 3rd party jQuery library that's being used to fancy-pants the scrollbar. Setting a 0 timeout didn't work, but it looks like setting it at 100 is going to work well enough for the requirements of this particular use case.